# Using kCTLineBreakByCharWrapping for CTTypesetter?

Tags: ios, core-text

I want to use CTTypesetter to layout text, I notice that CTTypesetter defaults to using `kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping`, from the docs I see that `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode` only applies to CTFramesetter, so I can't set break mode for CTTypesetter using this style specifier.

Question is: how do I change it to use `kCTLineBreakByCharWrapping`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a few days ago that what I was looking for is `CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak`.